# what causes the infinite loop in splice method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I have made a code that inserts '-' in front of upper case

```
const caseSwitch = (str) => {
  let strArr = [...str];
  for(let i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    if(strArr[i] === strArr[i].toUpperCase()) {
     strArr.splice(i, 1, '-' + strArr[i]);
    } 
  } return strArr.join('')
}

caseSwitch('camelCaseSnakeCase'); // 'camel-Case-Snake-Case'
```

but one thing made me really curious. In the splice part, when I change the number from 1 to 0

```
strArr.splice(i, 0, '-' + strArr[i]);
```

the warning sign 'RangeError: Potential infinite loop.' pops up.

but when I used 0, in another splice method that inserts '-' between two even numbers:

```
function insertHyphen(str) {
  var strArr = str.split('');
  var numArr = strArr.map(Number);
  for(var i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
    if(numArr[i-1]%2===0 && numArr[i]%2===0) {
        numArr.splice(i, 0, '-');
    }
  }
  return numArr.join('');
}
insertHyphen('112233445566'); //'112-2334-4556-6'
```

it works just fine. But don't know why two same method work different in both codes.

Comment: In the infinite loop version, you are replacing, say, "C" with "-C". When you increment the index *i*, it again points at "C" (because you inserted a "-" at its old index, so it got moved up one), so you add another "-C" and the index still points at "C", *ad infinitum*. So you need to increment *i* whenever you insert a "-".

Comment: As a side-note, you could use the following [one-liner](http://jsfiddle.net/po61aq43/) for the first one to replace your infinite loop issues: `return [...str].map(i => i === i.toUpperCase() ? "-"+i : i).join("");`. It's pretty much what you have written, except the `for` loop is replaced with a simple `map`.

Comment: @TylerRoper—what you've written is likely more efficient than the OP because you only generate 2 arrays and modify the values of the elements of the second. The OP's *splice* method generates one initial array plus another for each capital letter encountered, as well as modifying the elements. The first array can be avoided using `Array.prototype.map.call(s, c => (c == c.toUpperCase()? '-' : '') + c)` but I don't know if that's any more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Much easier, match all uppercase letters and replace it with itself prefixed with a -

```js
const caseSwitch = (str) => str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, "-$1");

console.log(caseSwitch('camelCaseSnakeCase'));
```

Comment: Yeah, cool, but it doesn't explain why the OP has their issue. ;-)